# apache camel http4 connectionTimeout

Tags: apache-camel

The requirement is to set the connectionTimeout for http endpoint. i am using http4 component and http protocol. httpClient.connectTimeout is working for https and not for http.

```
http4://<url>?keepAlive=true&httpClientMinThreads=10&httpClientMaxThreads=200&sync=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&bridgeEndpoint=true&httpClient.connectTimeout=1000
```

and tried setting the connectionTimeToLive=1 parameter also in http4 component bean and it is not working.

I found socketTimeout parameter is working. But the requirement is to set connectionTimeout.

Please suggest is there any way to set the connectionTimeout parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "httpClient" part from your parameter.

```
http4://<url>?connectTimeout=3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to the documentation here:
https://camel.apache.org/http4.html

You may need to use the `bridgeEndpoint=true` to allow proper redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the documentation isn't quite right. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723470/how-to-set-camel-http4-connection-timeout-options/65725661) for more details. The timeout parameters can be set via query param options, but they need to be prefixed with **httpClient.** . Here is what worked for me:

```
?httpClient.connectTimeout=10000&httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout=10000&httpClient.socketTimeout=30000
```

I verified by testing with ridiculously small values (1 ms) and it produced "read timed out" errors.

It looks the availble options for httpClient are the setter values on [RequestConfig.Builder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html).