# How to set Camel HTTP4 connection timeout options?

Tags: java, apache-camel

The documentation at [Camel HTTP4](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html#_http4_component_options) is quite clear that you can set the following options for the HTTP4 component: **connectionRequestTimeout**, **connectTimeout**, and **socketTimeout**.

However, these are listed as general component options, not query options in the documentation (and are ignored if set as query options -- they just get passed onto the HTTP endpoint when called). So I'm not sure how to set them. The HTTPComponent class does not seem to have any setter methods for these options.

The documentation does have a section [Using client timeout - SO_TIMEOUT](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html#_using_client_timeout_so_timeout), that links to unit test source where they set **httpClient.soTimeout** as a query option. However, when I try that I get an error:

> Failed to resolve endpoint:
> https4://myhost/myapi/v1?bridgeEndpoint=true&httpClient.soTimeout=1000 due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint.
> Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are
> properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{soTimeout=1000}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the documentation isn't quite right. All of those timeout parameters can be set via query param options, but they need to be prefixed with **httpClient.** . Here is what worked for me:

```
?httpClient.connectTimeout=10000&httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout=10000&httpClient.socketTimeout=30000
```

I verified by testing with ridiculously small values (1 ms) and it produced "read timed out" errors.

It looks the availble options for httpClient are the setter values on [RequestConfig.Builder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html).

Comment: The documentation needs some love for sure. Camel is changing fast so hard to keep everything up to date without some help. Will see if we can get this merged in to the docs somehow.